# Vertex packing on a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, np

Associate each node of an undirected graph with positive weight. The *vertex packing* problem is to find a subset of the nodes with the largest sum of weights, such that no two nodes with an edge between them are chosen.

What is the most efficient way of solving the vertex packing problem for a *bipartite* graph? I have been able to formulate it as a maximum flow problem with twice the number of nodes. Is there a more efficient, possibly direct, approach?

Comment: The problem is also called maximum (weighted) independent set. I should have searched around a little more before asking here.

Comment: Fig. 4 in the paper [Incremental Computation of Resource-Envelopes in Producer-Consumer Models](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-45193-8_45) seems to be more efficient. Your answer below does not seem to work for weighted version of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  P is a feasible solution for the vertex packing problem iff V-P is a feasible solution for the vertex cover problem. Thus a maximum vertex packing is equivalent to a minimum vertex cover. The minimum vertex cover is in turn equivalent to the maximum matching for bipartite graphs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did this? how do you transform the packing into the cover? and how are weights involved? This would solve the last problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833281/directed-maximum-weighted-bipartite-matching-allowing-sharing-of-start-end-verti/14990945#14990945