# Directed maximum weighted bipartite matching allowing sharing of start/end vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, matching

Let G (U u V, E) be a weighted directed bipartite graph (i.e. U and V are the two sets of nodes of the bipartite graph and E contains directed weighted edges from U to V or from V to U). Here is an example:

[image: bipartite directed and weighted graph]

In this case:

```
U = {A,B,C} 
V = {D,E,F} 
E = {(A->E,7), (B->D,1), (C->E,3), (F->A,9)}
```

**Definition:** *DirectionalMatching* (I made up this term just to make things clearer): set of directed edges that may share the start or end vertices. That is, if U->V and U'->V' both belong to a *DirectionalMatching* then V /= U' and V' /= U but it may be that U = U' or V = V'.

**My question:** How to efficiently find a *DirectionalMatching*, as defined above, for a bipartite directional weighted graph which maximizes the sum of the weights of its edges?

By *efficiently*, I mean polynomial complexity or faster, I already know how to implement a naive brute force approach.

In the example above the maximum weighted *DirectionalMatching* is: {F->A,C->E,B->D}, with a value of 13.

Formally demonstrating the equivalence of this problem to any other well known problem in graph theory would also be valuable.

Thanks!

**Note 1:**  This question is based on [Maximum weighted bipartite matching _with_ directed edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824320/maximum-weighted-bipartite-matching-with-directed-edges) but with the extra relaxation that it is allowed for edges in the matching to share the origin or destination. Since that relaxation makes a big difference, I created an independent question.

**Note 2:** This is a maximum **weight** matching. Cardinality (how many edges are present) and the number of vertices covered by the matching is irrelevant for a correct result. Only the maximum weight matters.

**Note 2:** During my research to solve the problem I found this paper, I think it would be helpful to others trying to find a solution: [Alternating cycles and paths in edge-coloured
multigraphs: a survey](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~gutin/paperstsp/alt.pdf)

**Note 3:** In case it helps, you can also think of the graph as its equivalent 2-edge coloured undirected bipartite multigraph. The problem formulation would then turn into: *Find the set of edges without colour-alternating paths or cycles which has maximum weight sum.*

**Note 4:** I suspect that the problem might be NP-hard, but I am not that experienced with reductions so I haven't managed to prove it yet.

**Yet another example**:

Imagine you had

4 vertices: `{u1, u2}` `{v1, v2}`

4 edges: `{u1->v1, u1->v2, u2->v1, v2->u2}`

Then, regardless of their weights, `u1->v2` and `v2->u2` cannot be in the same *DirectionalMatching*, neither can `v2->u2` and `u2->v1`. However `u1->v1` and `u1->v2` can, and so can `u1->v1` and `u2->v1`.

Comment: Is only me, or does this definition allows us to connect every nodes from the left to every nodes from the right, and it still will be "directional matching"?

Comment: Indeed, that would be a directional matching

Comment: what's the problem then? so let's take all the edges from left to right and from right to left 8) we can't take any more (there are none), so it will maximize the sum.

Comment: @K.Bulatov No, that is not a solution, please read the definition of *Directional Matching* carefully. For instance A->E cannot appear in the same matching as F->A

Comment: Wouldn't the maximum be at {F->A,C->E,B->D} where it is 13?

Comment: @cyon True! my bad, see? I really need an algorithm :) I corrected the question accordingly.

Comment: [Please do not post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). This question is at best borderline here, it's really more of a [cs.se] question and has been posted on [CSTheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/directed-maximum-weighted-bipartite-matching-allowing-sharing-of-start-end-verti), so I'm voting to close here.

Comment: @Gilles, I am sorry about the crossposting (I am new to stackexchange) and the question has been already closed in CSTheory

Comment: How is somebody with 31 reputation able to make a +150 bounty?

Comment: That's completely offtopic, but since you are asking ... The reputation is substracted at the time the bounty is created not when awarding it.

Comment: @fons: do you mean to say that they can share edges in one direction alone? i.e. in the direction which yields max weight matching.....

Comment: @Yash informally, I mean that only edges pointing to the opposite direction may share common vertices in the matching.

Comment: @fons this is an np problem. if you are just looking to reduce the computation time for your problem, i would suggest what i would do in these situations, i.e. using SIMD based programming like OpenCL. You can code your naive algorithm using OpenCL or CUDA. It wont reduce the complexity but the execution time will be reduced to a very large extent due to massive parallelism, Which will be easier than finding a method for reducing the complexity and proving that this method is true in all cases. Just saying you know, so that you can proceed with your work........

Comment: @Yash I assume you mean it's an NP-hard problem (since it's not a decision problem) and NP also contains P (which is what I was looking for). But even then, without a formal problem reduction to or from another NP-complete problem (like SAT3 as Vor suggests) that is just an unproven claim. And if that happens to be true, then, parallelization will be certainly a better option than complexity reduction (it won't give you 1 million dollars nor a turing award though ... bummer :)). But, let's have a reduction first, I am not fully convinced about Vor's proof, can you provide one?

Comment: @fons: I will let you know if I come up with something convincing.......

Comment: One correction to my last comment. Where I said **"to or from"** it should only say **"from"**.

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to be a well-studied problem for general (not just bipartite) undirected graphs with polynomial time algorithms: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumIndependentEdgeSet.html ... This is amusing considering the analog problem involving vertices is an NP-hard optimization problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_problem ... Intuition leads me astray in this territory.

Comment: @fons This problem requires further clarification. Please see my conversation with mhum below. It appears that the direction of the edges is irrelevant. If not, you need to clearly explain how, say, reversing A->E would change the result and why. From my convo with mhum it appears this question is not self consistent.

Comment: @TylerDurden Admittedly the example could be better, but I think that the defintion of Directional Matching is descriptive enough not to leave any questions. You just need to find the directional matching with the highest weight. The direction does matter, it's key to this problem. Imagine you had 4 vertices {u1, u2} {v1, v2} and 4 edges {u1->v1, u1->v2, u2->v1, v2->u2}  . u1->v2 and and v2->u2 cannot be in the same DirectionalMapping, neither can v2->u2 and u2->v1, however u1->v1 and u1->v2 can, and so can u1->v1 and u2->v1.

Comment: @TylerDurden This is not a maximum cardinality matching, the number of edges in the result doesn't matter. Neither does the number of vertices covered. It's about maximum weight, that's it. And, even if no example contains it explicitly, it is allowed to have edges like {A->B, B->A} everything is allowed as long as it's directional and bipartite. I should had maybe described the problem with it's equivalent 2-edge coloured bipartite multigraph ... but that's another story.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify this: is it ok to have solutions that do not include every vertex, and have the same vertex appear multiple times in a solution? If so, it is not a bipartite matching so the article is misnamed. (Bipartite implies a complete 1-to-1 matching).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a new undirected graph `G'` from `G` as follows.

1. `G'` has a node `(A, B)` with weight `w` for each directed edge `(A, B)` with weight `w` in `G`
2. `G'` has undirected edge `((A, B),(B, C))` if (A, B) and (B, C) are both directed edges in G

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Line_digraphs

Now find a maximal (weighted) independent vertex set in `G'`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_independent_set

### Edit: stuff after this point only works if all of the edge weights are the same - when the edge weights have different values its a more difficult problem (google "maximum weight independent vertex set" for possible algorithms)

Typically this would be an NP-hard problem. However, `G'` is a bipartite graph -- it contains only even cycles. Finding the maximal (weighted) independent vertex set in a bipartite graph is *not* NP-hard.

The algorithm you will run on `G'` is as follows.

1. Find the connected components of `G'`, say `H_1, H_2, ..., H_k`
2. For each `H_i` do a 2-coloring (say red and blue) of the nodes. The cookbook approach here is to do a depth-first search on `H_i` alternating colors. A simple approach would be to color each vertex in `H_i` based on whether the corresponding edge in `G` goes from `U` to `V` (red) or from `V` to `U` (blue).
3. The two options for which nodes to select from `H_i` are either all the red nodes or all the blue nodes. Choose the colored node set with higher weight. For example, the red node set has weight equal to `H_i.nodes.where(node => node.color == red).sum(node => node.w)`. Call the higher-weight node set `N_i`.
4. Your maximal weighted independent vertex set is now `union(N_1, N_2, ..., N_k)`.

Since each vertex in `G'` corresponds to one of the directed edges in `G`, you have your maximal DirectionalMatching.

Comment: Wow, as simple as modelling the problem with the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) instead. Skiena is right, again: [Design Graphs not Algorithms](http://books.google.nl/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=%22design+graphs+not+algorithms%22&source=bl&ots=z7bDOOGMZm&sig=kH1lyd7kcCWGob6KVbpPsX25ufY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yFAlUbz8NomX1AWTtICQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22design%20graphs%20not%20algorithms%22&f=false)!!! 

I haven't checked the whole solution yet (it's really late here) but I will do it first thing tomorrow (it looks like you are getting the bounty though :)).

Comment: Yeah, the section you referenced in that book summarizes pretty much exactly what I did in this answer: (1) transform the graph, (2) apply known algorithm (with a slight modification). Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: I haven't had time to check it yet (I am having a busy day). But since  this is the only promising answer (well, from my perspective until I confirm it) and the bounty is ending in 1 hour .... it's yours.

Comment: If you have difficulty getting it to work or find a fault in the algorithm, just comment here. I'm interested to hear whether it works out.

Comment: For step 2, isn't the coloring straightforward since G' is bipartite? Just use blue (red) for the nodes created from edges from U to V and red (blue) for the nodes created from V to U. I don't see why a depth-first search is required.

Comment: That's correct: you can just use that criterion for the 2-coloring at step 2. I jumped straight to the cookbook "2-color a bipartite graph" algorithm without realizing you could complete that step much more easily -- editing the answer to reflect your observation.

Comment: I think that the cookbook approach and the simplification are simply identical, or is there any other possible (non-isomorphic) 2-color vertex coloring if the graph is bipartite? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They're not identical in general. Typically you're computing a 2-coloring of a supposedly-bipartite graph to actually determine the two partite sets of nodes. Here we can deduce the two partite sets "on paper" (as you did) since we already have them from the original graph.

Comment: I see your point, but I cannot think of an example in which a different coloring can happen. Can you provide one?

Comment: Suppose I give you a graph `G` with vertex set `V` and edge set `E`. I tell you it's bipartite, meaning *there exists* a partition of `V` such that edges in `E` only go between the two partite sets, but I don't actually tell you how to partition `V`. As an example, you might have an application where a user gets to define a graph using a UI where they can add/remove nodes and edges on a canvas. Suppose that you require the graph the user makes to be bipartite. How will you check this property? And if it is bipartite, how will you determine how to split the vertices into the partite sets?

Comment: I think your scenario may be too general. So let me reformulate my question, if you don't mind. Sticking to your specific solution, can you provide a specific example of the original G for which G' in step 2 has two non-isomorphic 2-vertex colorings?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that's all you were asking.  The example graph in your original question had an isolated edge.  Since you can flip the node colors in any connected component, the 2-colorings will in general not be isomorphic.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant by isomorphic. For each independent subgraph, you could in principle change the coloring (but there are still only two colorings and no search is necessary, it's a matter of picking a color for each side). Additionally, since we are looking for the maximum sum anyhow, this won't really make a difference.

Comment: I have an example that I dont understand how this will solve: `U={A,C,E}` `V={B,D}` and `E={(A->B,10), (B->C,1), (C->D,1), (D->E,10)}`. I would expect maximum value be 20, but with a 2-coloring it ends up with 11?

Comment: @viblo You're actually correct, that's a problem with the algorithm I gave.  The error in the algorithm is that finding the maximum independent vertex set *in a weighted graph* actually is not solved by what I described in my answer.  The overall approach of finding a maximum independent vertex set in G' is correct, but the second part of the answer needs to be fixed because of this.  Good catch.

Comment: @TimothyShields I think it should still be polynomial due to Köning's theorem. How about relying on maximum-weight matching? First transform `G'` (with vertex weight function `w'`) into edge-weighted graph `G''` with edge weight function `w''`, defined as  `w''((A,B)) = w'(A) + w'(B)` where `(A,B)` denotes the edge between `A` and `B`. Then apply the Hungarian algorithm to get the maximum weight matching (`MWM`). Then, to compute the maximum independent set: for every edge `(A,B)` in `MWM`, pick the node with highest initial weight `w'` plus all the vertices not incident to edges in `MWM`.

Comment: @fons Your algorithm is incorrect I think.  Search google for maximum weight independent vertex set and you will see that the algorithms for it are very nontrivial.

Comment: @TimothyShields It is incorrect indeed, sorry. Just found a counterexample. I will look for an algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: @TimothyShields It can be solved in a very simple way by adapting G' to a flow network and computing the maximum flow. If you are interested I can provide you the details so that you can update your answer.

Comment: So, what's needed is the following. Add two extra nodes, source (`s`) and sink (`t`). Build `N`, a flow network, from the bipartite version of your `G'`, that is `G'=(U union V,E,w')`, where `U` and `V` contain the nodes, `E` contains the edges, and `w'` is the weight function of the nodes. In order to do so, we need to connect `s` and `t`and provide capacities to all edges. We do it as follows, connect `s` to every `u` in `U` with a capacity of `w'(u)`, connect every `v` in `V` to every `t` with a capacity of `w'(v)`. Maintain the edges from `E` and assign them an infinite capacity.

Comment: Compute the maximum flow of the network (`mf`). The total weight of the maximum weight independent set is `TotalWeigth(G') - mf`. And the nodes providing it are the ones still reachable from `s` in `U` and from `t` in `V` after applying the maximum flow algorithm.

Comment: Either I dont understand how you do the rewrite or it doesnt work I think. :) What are U and V? Could you write out N for the graph in your original question?

Comment: @viblo In my example, after transforming the graph to G', N is:

{(s->(A,E),7), (s->(B,D),1), (s->(C,E),3), ((A,E)->(F,A),infinite), ((F,A)->t,9)} The maximum flow is 7, and the total weight of the maximum-weighted independent set is (7+1+3+9)-7 = 13 . The vertices part of the set are the ones still accesible (those for which flow < weight) that is: (B,D) with flow 0 and weight 1, (C,E) with flow 0 and weight 3,and (F,A) with flow 7 and weight 9

Comment: I tried to apply the before mentioned algo with the flows on this example: G=({A, C, E}, {B, D}, {(A, B, 3), (B, C, 1), (C, D, 1), (D, E, 3)}.  In this case the G' bipartite line graph  is ({(A,B), (C, D)}, {(B, C), (D, E)}, {((A, B), (B, C)), ((B, C), (C, D)), ((C, D), (D, E))}), with node weights (A, B) -> 3, (B, C) -> 1, (C, D) -> 1, (D, E) -> 3. So it's easy to see that the maximum weight directional matching is 6, but the max flow in the corresponding network is 4, so sum(weights) - max_flow = 4. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score -2):

This problem can be solved in polynomial time using the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). The "proof" by Vor above is wrong.

The method of structuring the problem for the above example is as follows:

```
   D E F
A  # 7 9  
B  1 # #
C  # 3 #
```

where "#" means negative infinity. You then resolve the matrix using the Hungarian algorithm to determine the maximum matching. You can multiply the numbers by -1 if you want to find a minimum matching.

Comment: How would you adapt the Hungarian Algorithm to this case which includes: 1) directed edges, and 2) the possibility for edges in the solution to share vertices?

Comment: The fact that the edges are directed is irrelevant. If a vertex connects to multiple vertices then that results in multiple possible weightings. For example, in my example above A has two weightings, but B and C only one. You could just as well have edges between every single vertex, which would result in a full matrix with no "#" values.

Comment: Ok. But if in the original asker's problem the edge from A->E were reversed to E->A, then I understood that A<-E, A->F, B->D, C->E would be the correct solution (but would not be a valid solution under the Hungarian Algorithm). This is what I thought they meant by "set of directed edges that may share the start or end vertices".

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what a "directional matching" is. However, your solution of "A<-E, A->F, B->D, C->E" is not a bipartite matching because there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between vertices of the two sides.

Comment: That is exactly correct. It is not a bipartite matching. The asker has specifically said that they are looking for something they have termed a "Directional Matching" (not a standard term), defined above in the question. The graph itself is defined as bipartite, but the requested solutions are not bipartite matchings, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, well in this case, I guess what you are saying is that {E->A,F->A} is considered as a single "directional matching" with a value of 16, however, this is still impossible because if you do this match, then how do you match B/C to just D, you can't. It is not really clear what the objective is, if it is not a 1-to-1 matching. I mean if you are allowing any so called "match", why not match everything (which is exactly what your "solution" above does, including all 4 edges)?

Comment: Yes, in the modified case I stated, I think the solution would be to select all edges. The thing which prevents this from always being the solution is the idea that if A->B and B->C, you can't select both A->B and B->C to be in a solution since the head of one edge intersects the tail of another edge. "Matching" is perhaps an inapt term here. I think the asker is requesting a set of directed edges such that there are no heads overlapping any tails.

Comment: In that case your solution violates that rule, because if we switch A->E to E->A, then you can't have both C->E and E->A in the solution because a head is overlapping a tail.

Comment: Whoops. You are correct about that and I was wrong. The solution in the case where the edge is flipped to E->A would be A->F, E->A, B->D. Sorry about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24787/discussion-between-tyler-durden-and-mhum)